# Pandas qcut with infinite values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to have bins with infinite values on the left and right. This worked in older pandas versions (at least 1.1.5) but not in 1.5.

```
pd.qcut([1,2,3,4,5,-np.inf, np.inf], q=3, duplicates="drop")
```

results in `ValueError: missing values must be missing in the same location both left and right sides`.

When omitting the `duplicates` keyword the following error occurs:

```
ValueError: Bin edges must be unique: array([nan,  2.,  4., nan]).
You can drop duplicate edges by setting the 'duplicates' kwarg
```

My workaround is to replace `np.inf` with with really high numbers such as `1e9`, but this is not as nice as using np-inf. Is this a bug or intended that `np.inf` is treated as `nan`?

Comment: Check this issue and related bugs: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/21932

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming pandas is using np.percentile? A similar issue is this one: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/21091

Comment: `percentile` are for numbers between [0-100], `quantile` for [0-1] and yes Pandas use numpy under the hood

Comment: works fine in Pandas 1.1.3 and Numpy 1.21.2

Comment: Yes, I noticed that as well. So something must have changed in the versions after. Not sure if this was intended.